# Is Selenium (Python) a good method to download a large number of files from a webpage?

Tags: python, selenium

I apologize if this type of question is not welcome here.
I have a project that I want to achieve but I am wondering if the method I use is a correct one.

**Goal**: Download automatically files from a website -> https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmaps/packs.

To be precise it needs to download at least 100 files from the links on the webpage.

**Method I used**: Selenium with Python. Using this seems kind of slow, so I am wondering if it is just because my code is poorly made or is it because the method I used is not a good one.

Thank you

```
# Imports 

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

## Functions
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\DOWNLOAD\\Nouveau dossier\\chr web driver\\chromedriver')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

def sw(a):
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[a])
    return 

def close():
    driver.close()
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    driver.close()
    return 

def current():
    x = driver.current_window_handle
    return x

def init(username,password): # This function connects to the website 
    str_usr = str(username)
    str_pass = str(password)
    driver.get('http://osu.ppy.sh/beatmaps/packs')
    assert len(driver.window_handles) == 1
    BM_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div[3]/div/div[20]/a/div[1]')
    BM_1.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    cnct = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div[3]/div/div[20]/div/div/a')
    cnct.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    # Entering id
    sbar_1 =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/form/div[1]/input[1]')
    sbar_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/form/div[1]/input[2]')
    sbar_1.send_keys(str_usr)
    sbar_2.click()
    sbar_2.send_keys(str_pass)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    b_connect = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/form/div[4]/div/button/div')
    b_connect.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    return 

def click_beatmap(val): # Select beatmap and download it
    x = str(val)
    BM_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[' + x + ']/a/div[1]')
    BM_1.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    DBM_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[' + x + ']/div/div/a')
    DBM_1.click()
    d_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div/a[2]')
    d_2.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    return 

def close_ads(nbr): # Close ads
    sw(2)
    driver.close()
    wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
    sw(1)
    driver.close()
    wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(1))
    sw(0)
    return

def back(d): # Goes back to return to the osu! webpage
    driver.back()
    time.sleep(2)
    if d ==0:
        driver.back()
        time.sleep(1)
    time.sleep(3)
    return 

def download(number,X): # Main program
    for i in range(number):      
        time.sleep(5)
        click_beatmap(X)
        if len(driver.window_handles) != 1:
            a = len(driver.window_handles)
            close_ads(a-1)
        X = X-1
        back(i)
        assert len(driver.window_handles) == 1
        driver.refresh()
        z = driver.window_handles
        print(i,'étape', z)
    return 

# Main
usr = 'username'   # obviously, need to enter proper username and password
pw = 'password'
init(usr,pw)
time.sleep(3)
download(10,20)
```

Comment: You should not use absolute xpath in your code because any minor change in the xpath would break your code. You can download urls in two stages - 1-List all the download urls. 2 - Use a Python library like Apache commons IO of Java to download files from those urls. 1 can be done by either scraping all links from a page or by generating the links yourself. You could generate the links yourself if the links have a pattern. For example links might be like this - www.mystuff.com/downloads/{file_id} where file_id can be like file_11, file_12 etc.

Comment: Ty for the answer.1-, I tried other methods to locate elements on the webpage and the only one I was able to use was the XPath one, even if it seems far from ideal.2-IDK if you saw the site but the URLs are not directly on the website, it opens a Mediafire webpage and the URLs of each file don't have proper patterns(but maybe your point still applies).

Comment: Are you familiar with APIs or HTTP requests? It'd be ideal if you didn't have to deal with the UI in order to download all the files. I don't have an account on that website, but if you could have your script create requests to download the files, that would be ideal

Comment: Ty for the answer! 1- I am not familiar with either APIs or HTTP requests, I have done some quick research and I am not sure if I understand completely what it can do for my problem. 2- When you say create request, I suppose you mean API requests ? 3- My method isn't good and I should give up with this method?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue I see here is the different wait strategies used throughout your program, which may account for some of the slowness. You are also using `driver.implicitly_wait()` incorrectly here. There is a mix of `driver.implicitly_wait`, `time.sleep()`, and `WebDriverWait` in here, which is heavily discouraged Selenium practice. You can usually just pick one strategy and stick with it, with the exception of special cases.

First -- implicit wait is a setting on the driver, not a command that should be executed repeatedly. You should run `driver.implicitly_wait()` only once at the beginning of your driver declaration, and that's about it. This is a global setting that tells the driver instance to wait up to 2 seconds between each action, depending on load times.

I would refactor this code to use *only* `WebDriverWait` and get rid of the `time.sleep()` and `implicitly_wait` statements.

Lastly, I would also refactor all of your XPath statements to use `//` notation -- the ones you are currently using are brittle and prone to breaking easily.

This code is quite long, and I cannot refactor all of it, but I will refactor part of it to give you an idea of how to proceed. If you have any specific questions about sections of code, feel free to leave a comment and I am happy to clarify.

```
# Imports 

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

## Functions
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\DOWNLOAD\\Nouveau dossier\\chr web driver\\chromedriver')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

def sw(a):
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[a])
    return 

def close(): # refactored this -- call close() and quit(), remove implicit wait
    driver.close() # close both windows
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
    return 

def current():
    x = driver.current_window_handle
    return x

def init(username,password): # This function connects to the website 
    str_usr = str(username)
    str_pass = str(password)
    driver.get('http://osu.ppy.sh/beatmaps/packs')
    assert len(driver.window_handles) == 1

    # click first beatmap link to trigger sign in
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Beatmap Pack #831']"))).click()

    # wait for sign in link to appear, then click it
    sign_in_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='signed in']")))
    sign_in_link.click()

    # wait for ID to exist, enter ID
    username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']")))
    username.send_keys(str_user)

    # enter password - no need to invoke WebDriverWait here because password element exists at the same time as username, which we waited on earlier.   
    password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name='password']')
    password.click()
    password.send_keys(str_pass)

    # click sign in
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[div/span]").click()
    return
```

I would continue this pattern and remove all of your `driver.implicitly_wait` statements, and try to replace `time.sleep()` with `WebDriverWait` whenever possible. Your XPaths can also be refactored to be much more simple. Here's a sample loop of how I would iterate the list of Beatmap links and click each one:

```
# locate all links
beatmap_links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(), 'Beatmap Pack')]")))

# iterate links and click each one
for link in beatmap_links:

    # click the link
    link.click()

    # wait for download

    # go back
    driver.back()

    # refresh list of beatmap_link elements to avoid StaleElement exception
    beatmap_links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(), 'Beatmap Pack')]")))
```

Hopefully this gets you started on refactoring the rest of it.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to apply the concepts you gave me